# Output values or stdout of another script in text field

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a script build like (my_functions.py):

```
def a():
   a_str = "this is a"
   print(a_str)
   return a_str

def b():
   b_str = "this is b"
   print(b_str)
   return b_str

def c():
   c_str = "this is c"
   print(c_str)
   return c_str
```

Now, in PyQt5 I want to be able to select, what functions from my_functions.py should be executed. Pressing the button "Start" should execute selected functions.

My code looks like this (my_gui.py):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QCheckBox, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton

# import my_functions as fcts

class checkdemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(checkdemo, self).__init__(parent)

        left_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setFixedSize(1200, 800)

        self.l1 = QLabel("Select required output\n")
        left_layout.addWidget(self.l1)

        self.b1 = QCheckBox("from def a()")
        self.b1.setChecked(True)
        self.b1.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.btnstate(self.b1))
        left_layout.addWidget(self.b1)

        self.b2 = QCheckBox("from def b()")
        self.b2.setChecked(True)
        self.b2.toggled.connect(lambda: self.btnstate(self.b2))
        left_layout.addWidget(self.b2)

        self.b3 = QCheckBox("from def c()")
        self.b3.setChecked(True)
        self.b3.toggled.connect(lambda: self.btnstate(self.b3))
        left_layout.addWidget(self.b3)

        button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.clickme)
        left_layout.addWidget(button)

        left_layout.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(left_layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("GUI for my functions")


    def btnstate(self, b):
        if b.text() == "Button1":
            if b.isChecked():
                # what should I do here?
                pass
            else:
                # what should I do here?
                pass

        if b.text() == "Button2":
            if b.isChecked():
                # what should I do here?
                pass
            else:
                # what should I do here?
                pass

        if b.text() == "Button3":
            if b.isChecked():
                # what should I do here?
                pass
            else:
                # what should I do here?
                pass

    def UiComponents(self):

        button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.clickme)

    def clickme(self):
        # add my function here?
        pass


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = checkdemo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, I am stuck and can't figure out, how to proceed? How can I print the results to a textfield in PyQt5 and connect these two scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Since the functions are only executed when the start button is clicked, there's no use in doing something when the related checkboxes are selected or not, and you can check which one is actually checked when clicking the button.

```
class checkdemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        self.result = QLineEdit()
        left_layout.addWidget(self.result)
        # ...

    def clickme(self):
        results = []
        if self.b1.isChecked():
            results.append(fcts.a())
        if self.b2.isChecked():
            results.append(fcts.b())
        if self.b3.isChecked():
            results.append(fcts.c())

        self.result.setText(', '.join(results) if results else 'Nothing done')
```